Constant problems when reinstalling addon 4.2
So I've been developing addons for my workplace for over 2 years in blender 3.5 and previous versions. Now we are planing an update to 4.2 LTS and I'm updating and creating new ones and I am just unable to make them work.
Previously we would install python libraries by pip and just call them from the addons. I'm aware that now yoiu have to package them in '.\wheels' and list them in the 'blender_,manifest.toml'.
First time I installed the addon, everything was fine. After updating some minor stuff (panel distribution) I can't reinstall it, it just wont work. I'm constanly getting library errors and permissions errors. The worst thing is that every now and then I will go and manually erase everything the addon installed and it will work and other times it wont. I am really losing my mind because the behavior is not consistant at all.
Here is an example of type of error I get.
Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.2\4.2\scripts\modules\_bpy_internal\extensions\wheel_manager.py", line 428, in apply_action
    _zipfile_extractall_safe(zip_fh, local_dir_site_packages, local_dir)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.2\4.2\scripts\modules\_bpy_internal\extensions\wheel_manager.py", line 222, in _zipfile_extractall_safe
    zip_fh.extract(member, path_restrict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.2\4.2\python\Lib\zipfile.py", line 1664, in extract
    return self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.2\4.2\python\Lib\zipfile.py", line 1735, in _extract_member
    open(targetpath, "wb") as target:
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Antonio GG\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\4.2\\extensions\\.local\\lib\\python3.11\\site-packages\\pyproj\\database.cp311-win_amd64.pyd'

It's bad enough that I have to zip the addon everytime I want to test something but not been able to install it after the first time is just frustating.
Does anyone gave any clue of what's happeing?
TL;DR: Self developed addons will only install the first time and crash when reinstalling.

I would recommend using the VSCode extensions for developing Blender add-ons (recently updated for the new 4.2 way of working).
If you are using that extension and VSCode, every time you change something and save the file it will update the add-on inside of Blender without having to reload Blender or re-zip anything.
I definitely have more of a hard time making add-ons on windows because of issues with permissions, and sometimes just running Blender as administrator helps (so that Blender can successfully move / remove / create files when needed).
